# Is there a simple way to convert a CSV with 0-indexed paths as keys to JSON with Miller?

Tags: json, csv, miller

Consider the following CSV:

```
email/1,email/2
abc@xyz.org,bob@pass.com
```

You can easily convert it to JSON (taking into account the paths defined by the keys) with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```sh
mlr --icsv --ojson --jflatsep '/' cat file.csv
```

```json
[ { "email": ["abc@xyz.org", "bob@pass.com"] } ]
```

Now, if the paths are 0-indexed in the CSV (which is surely more common):

```
email/0,email/1
abc@xyz.org,bob@pass.com
```

Then, *without prior knowledge of the fields names*, it seams that you'll have to rewrite the whole conversion:

<sub>**edit:** replaced the hard-coded `/` with `FLATSEP` builtin variable:</sub>

```sh
mlr --icsv --flatsep '/' put -q '
    begin { @labels = []; print "[" }

    # translate the original CSV header from 0-indexed to 1-indexed
    NR == 1 {
        i = 1;
        for (k in $*) {
            @labels[i] = joinv( apply( splita(k,FLATSEP), func(e) {
                return typeof(e) == "int" ? e+1 : e
            }), FLATSEP );
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    NR > 1 { print @object, "," }

    # create an object from the translated labels and the row values
    o = {};
    i = 1;
    for (k,v in $*) {
        o[@labels[i]] = v;
        i += 1;
    }
    @object = arrayify( unflatten(o,FLATSEP) );

    end { if (NR > 0) { print @object } print "]" }
' file.csv
```

I would like to know if I'm missing something obvious, like a command line option or a way to rename the fields with the `put` verb, or maybe something else? You're also welcome to give your insights about the previous code, as I'm not really confident in my Miller's programming skills.

---

**Update:**

With @aborruso [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71015190/3387716) of pre-processing the CSV header, this could be reduced to:
<sup>**note:** I didn't keep the `regextract` part because it means knowing the CSV header in advance.</sup>

```sh
mlr --csv -N --flatsep '/' put '
    NR == 1 {
        for (i,k in $*) {
            $[i] = joinv( apply( splita(k,FLATSEP), func(e) {
                return typeof(e) == "int" ? e+1 : e
            }), FLATSEP );
        }
    }
' file.csv |
mlr --icsv --flatsep '/' --ojson cat
```

Even if there are workarounds like using the `rename` verb (when you know the header in advance) or pre-processing the CSV header, I still hope that Miller's author could add an extra command-line option that would deal with this kind of **0‑indexed** external data; adding a `DSL` function like `arrayify0` (and `flatten0`) could also prove useful in some cases.

Comment: You could ask to the author, open a new issue here https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if I'm missing something obvious, like a command line option or a way to rename the fields with put verb, or maybe something else?

Starting from this

```
email/0,email/1
abc@xyz.org,bob@pass.com
```

you can use implicit CSV header and run

```
mlr --csv -N put 'if (NR == 1) {for (k in $*) {$[k] = "email/".string(int(regextract($[k],"[0-9]+"))+1)}}' input.csv
```

to have

```
email/1,email/2
abc@xyz.org,bob@pass.com
```

Comment: So you'd process the CSV by column number, transform the header in the original CSV, then pipe it to another `mlr` command for the JSON convertion?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, it seems to me clean and it does what you want